# Console.Read not returning my int32

Tags: c#

I don't get why my integer isn't coming out correctly, Console.Read() method says it's returning an integer, why isn't WriteLine displaying it correctly?

```
int dimension;
dimension = Console.Read();
Console.WriteLine(""+ dimension);
```

Comment: What did you input? What was output?

Comment: A whole number. When I put in 10, it comes out as 49. I tried typecasting but it stays 49.

Comment: Your code is working exactly like it should.  You are reading exactly one character.  If you want to read in **10** then you should be using **ReadLine()** this of course does not address the fact you code has a lot of possible problems.

Answer (score 6):

`Console.Read()` only returns the first character of what was typed. You should be using `Console.ReadLine()`:

**Example:**

```
int suppliedInt;

Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number greater than zero");
Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out suppliedInt);

if (suppliedInt > 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("You entered: " + suppliedInt);
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid number. Press any key to exit");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Additional Resources:**

MSDN - [`Console.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx)

MSDN - [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx)

Comment: `In real life, you should use Int32.TryParse() and handle the exception` But `TryParse` doesn't throw, that's the point of it.

Comment: @Joren, `exception` obviously wasn't the right word to use in that context. I've updated my answer to provide the "real world" portion of what I mentioned.

Comment: I would do: `if(Int32.TryParse())` to check if conversion succeeded then output result, because input can be < 0

Comment: @Reniuz, you could go lots of different ways depending on the requirements (which weren't really stated in the OP). This is just a quick example to get them thinking in the right direction.

Comment: I know :) I gave you upvote, but added note in comment that's it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Console.Read` method returns only a single character wrapped in an `int`, so that is only applicable if you are reading a number that is only one digit long, otherwise you'll always get only the first digit.

Since the return value of `Read` is actually a character, you cannot use it directly as an integer, you would need to parse it from character to integer.

But assuming that you want a number that is longer than one digit, then you really need to use `Console.ReadLine` instead and convert the input to an integer using `int.TryParse`. If `int.TryParse` returns `false` you can warn the user that he provided an invalid input and ask for the dimension again.

Sample code:

int dimension;

```
bool isValidDimension;
do
{
    Console.Write("Dimension: ");

    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    isValidDimension = int.TryParse(input, out dimension);

    if (!isValidDimension)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid dimension... please try again.");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
} while (!isValidDimension);
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx):

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Int32 The next character from the input stream, or
>   negative one (-1) if there are currently no more characters to be
>   read.

Answer (score 0):

you should it as follow

```
static void Main() 
{
    int Number;
    string strNumber;

    strNumber = Console.ReadLine();
    Number = int.Parse(strNumber);
    Console.WriteLine("" + dimension);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is returning but you're not seeing, would you please see below code block:

You are not be able to see the output if the output window doesn't stay.

```
int dimension;
dimension = Console.Read();
Console.WriteLine("" + dimension);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Console.Read() returns ASCII code of first symbol in input. You can do

```
int dimension;
dimension = Console.Read();
Console.WriteLine(""+ (char)dimension);
```

and you'll see right first symbol in input, as

```
(char)dimension
```

will give you symbol by it's ASCII code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 0;
if(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
{
    // Do your calculations with 'a' 
}
else
{
    // Some warnings
}
```